# Oracle constrain with regexp_like

Tags: regex, oracle, constraints

I need to create a constrain in a table. I need a field with only letters (A...Z) and parenthesis, ampersand, pipe and space ('(',')','&','|',' ').

I tried with the following but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE SCPOMGR.U_CLUSTER ADD 
CONSTRAINT U_CLUSTER_CHK_EQUATION
CHECK (regexp_like (equation, '[A-z]|[chr(124)]|[chr(38)]|[chr(40)]|[chr(41)]|[chr(32)]'))
ENABLE
VALIDATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex: `^[A-Za-z()&| ).]*$`

For more details: https://regex101.com/r/uH1yL9/1

`[A-z]` is not the same as `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is it also possible to use reg_exp to avoid two consequent letters (AB, AC, BD, ...) and two symbols (&|, &&, ...).
I just want a letter and a symbol: A&B|C&(D|E)

Comment: `^[()&| ).]?(?:[A-Za-z][()&| ).])*[A-Za-z]?$` should do the job. But keep in mind that it will also match an empty string. What are your requirements? Do you need to start or end with a letter or a symbol?

Comment: It should work, I will test. The scope is to create a field where the user have to write a pseudo-sql condition (& for AND and | for OR) where A, B, C, ... are the conditions written in a different related table

Answer (score 0):

**Untested** you can give this a try

```
'^[[:alpha:][:space:]\(\&\)\.]+$'
```